# Is it possible to connect to the testnet by mobile using Nethereum?

Tags: testnets, nethereum

Yesterday I start with smart contracts and deploy a simple one at the testnet. Only downloaded latest version of the wallet and clicked button to upload the smart contract. Is it possible to reach it by the mobile using nethereum or have I to run a private testnet where I have to set RPC while running geth?

Answer (score 1):

There is a mobile application called [Jaxx](https://jaxx.io/) where you can send or receive some ethers. It supports also smart contracts as well. And in bonus, the code is open source so you can fit according to your needs.

Comment: I need to build this app by myself with xamarin. Jaxx is a nice example but my question is: Have I to run my own private ethereum, geth with an IP and port or does also the testnet where I depoly yesterday my smart contract is reachable in such a way? For the private testnet I only call nethereums web3 and add here parameters like IP and port where it has to connect. Is there something for the testnet?

Comment: Oh okay, I miss understood your question. So you can have a look here then:http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10200/how-to-connect-web3js-to-mainnet-or-testnet