# what is the ethereum live network?

Tags: cpp-ethereum

By which I can connect the ethereum live network.

```
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('http://192.168.3.48:8045'))
```

Here I want to put a ethereum live network .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have Geth installed globally,  running the command `geth` in your terminal will connect. As follow,

[image]

If don't have it installed, refer [this](https://www.ethereum.org/cli) find how to install a client including geth.

If you are using windows this [post](https://www.deepdotweb.com/2017/05/25/tutorial-run-full-ethereum-node-windows/) may help you guiding through that.

Refer [this GitHub wiki page](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Connecting-to-the-network) to get an idea about connecting to networks in general

Refer [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10200/how-to-connect-web3js-to-mainnet-or-testnet) as well.

And option `--rpc` together with `geth` (i.e. `geth --rpc`) will open the HTTP_RPC server (by default address is localhost and port is 8545. Check [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options) for more options). This will start running a full node with RPC port open. Then you can use your above command.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a node running (that is connected to the "mainnet"), fully synced and has the relevant RPC ports open, then this should work.

If you don't want to run  a full node locally - or a light client - you could always use [Infura's "mainnet" end-point](https://infura.io/docs/#endpoints)

Comment: Using infaura it is fine . But how could I create and and run my own node ? please tell the process .

Comment: using infura how could I use 'sendTransaaction' ?